# On Ubuntu, maximize a window over two screens

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-unity

EDIT: I ended up installing KDE and everything worked as expected. I think that there must be something built into Unity that simply will not allow windows to stretch over two screens in the way I was trying to do it.

---

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty with the Unity WM. The computer has two screens, each plugged into the internal display. In the Display settings panel, the two screens are stacked vertically.

All I want is for maximized windows to cover both screens. Actually, what I REALLY need is to do this from a script. I tried wmctrl, but no matter what, windows always stop at the edge of a screen.

If I drag a window across the border and then stretch it manually, it works, but this is not what I'm trying to do: it needs to be something I can automate.

I tried this in on another computer with the same version of Ubuntu but with KDE instead of Unity and it worked. I think it would be overkill to move to KDE just for that, though.

I tried modifying values in CCSM and I tried several other settings, but nothing made windows maximize over both screens and no setting allowed vmctrl to place a window over both screens.

Surely, this must be doable. How can a script place a window over both my screens?

Comment: Which vga adapter are you using and which Xorg driver?

Comment: I moved to KDE and it worked. I'll modify the question.

Comment: Here is a solution with CompizConfig Settings Manager: [Ask Ubuntu: How to maximise a window across two monitors?](http://askubuntu.com/a/94192/170612)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written above, I gave up trying to make this work in Unity and moved to KDE. Everything worked fine in KDE.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the exact opposite - do you know, by any chance, how to disable this behaviour in KDE?

Comment: @AtomHeartFather Switch to Unity? :D